# Opencart Social Login Module extension's installation

Tags: facebook, opencart2.x, opencart-module

how to install social login module in opencart 2.0.1.1 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a bug you should rather report to the creator of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug while installing social login module for multistores, i have fixed that issue by myself